# Getting the lastest contract signed by each doctor

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table which keeps the info about the renewal and expiration of the doctors' job contracts in a hospital:

[image]

As can be seen, each doctor (`Doc_ID`) appears more than once, which makes sense if we consider that after the expiration of a contract a new one is (usually) signed.

From this table, I would like to take the last contract signed by each doctor. I mean something like this:

```
Doc_ID  Hire_Date   End_Date
71      8/1/1985    8/1/1995
72      9/15/1992   9/15/2002
73      2/10/1995   2/10/2005
74      12/4/2000   12/4/2010
75      9/1/1985    9/1/1995
76      6/23/1991   6/23/2001
```

Where the row related to earlier contracts is skipped.

My attempt was this:

```
SELECT TOP 12 Doc_ID, Hire_Date, End_Date
FROM Hire_info
ORDER BY End_Date DESC
```

This works because I know the total number of doctors in the hospital, but

1. What happens if this is not known?
2. In my database a job contract lasts for 10 years for each of them, but what happens if some doctor is hired by a 5-year contract. Using the script above this doctor will appear more than once.

How can I avoid these issues?

Comment: For, I think, SS 2012+, check out `Last_Value` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Lamak's method, which is correct +1, you can use this:

```
SELECT  Doc_ID,
        Hire_Date,
        End_Date
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Doc_ID, Max(End_Date) dt FROM tbl GROUP BY Doc_ID) t2 ON
t2.Doc_ID = tbl.Doc_ID and t2.dt = tbl.End_Date
```

Note that if `End_Date` can be `NULL`, as in the contract hasn't ended yet, you need to account for that.

```
SELECT  Doc_ID,
        Hire_Date,
        End_Date
FROM tbl
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Doc_ID, Max(ISNULL(End_Date,'12/31/2999')) dt FROM tbl GROUP BY Doc_ID) t2 ON
t2.Doc_ID = tbl.Doc_ID and t2.dt = ISNULL(tbl.End_Date,'12/31/2999')
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnBustos :)

Comment: The use of `Group By` there is pretty neat. Pretty clever way to do it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Doc_ID ORDER BY Hire_Date DESC)
    FROM dbo.Hire_Info
)
SELECT  Doc_ID,
        Hire_Date,
        End_Date
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your table has a Primary Key (PK), you can use the following script.

```
select Doc_ID,Hire_Date,End_Date from Hire_info H
where H.PK in
(
select top 1 HI.PK from Hire_info HI where HI.Doc_ID = H.Doc_ID
and Hire_Date is not null 
order by Hire_Date desc
)
order by Doc_ID
```